# Get the year of a specified month in previous 12 months?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I'm trying:

```
$m = 'December';
$from = date('jS M Y', strtotime("first day of previous $m"));
```

But it's not returning a date. In use, the month will be selected by a user from a dropdown box. However, I have tried typing 'December' in place of the variable directly and it still doesn't work.

I'm expecting it to return "1st Dec 2012".

Comment: `$from = date('jS M Y', strtotime("first day of $m last year"));`?

Comment: What if they select January? As of today, that would give us a date 17 months ago (not in previous 12 months).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your code that `$m` is the current month in text format, you can use something like:

```
$m = 'June';
$m = date('m', strtotime($m));
$c = (mktime(0,0,0,$m, 1) < time()) ? mktime(0,0,0,$m,1) : mktime(0,0,0,$m,1, date("Y") -1);
$from = date('jS M Y', $c);
```

What this does is it converts the month to a numerical value and stores in place of string value.  Then it assigns `$c` to either the month of the current year, or the month of the previous year, depending on if the month of the current year is less than the current time stamp.  So if the current timestamp is `June 1st at 1am`, then the current year will still be selected.

[**DEMO**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/cwi-9gs)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$m = '12'; // set here numeric form of month
echo $from = date('jS M Y', strtotime("01-".$m."-".(date("Y") -1)));
```

**OR**

```
$m = 'December';
echo $from = date('jS M Y', strtotime("01-".$m."-".(date("Y") -1)));
```

## Output

```
1st Dec 2012
```

## Codepad




## Codepad2

## EDIT

Try this, this is tested for january as well as december

```
$m = '01';
$new_m = date('m'); // get current month
if($m > $new_m) {
   $year = date("Y") -1;
} else {
   $year = date("Y");
}
echo $from = date('jS M Y', strtotime("01-".$m."-".$year));
```

## Output

```
1st Jan 2013
```

## Codepad

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but this seems to work for December, but if I put January in, it returns "1st Jan 2012" instead of "1st Jan 2013".  The date would be in the previous 12 months.

Comment: @PeterSnow Means you are saying that if the month is passed then it should show current year and if month is coming afterwards then it should show last year?

Comment: Yes, that's another way of putting it.

Comment: Thanks Yogesh. I've accepted Jon's answer above because (a) it arrived 2 mins earlier and (b) I like the compactness of his code, but +1 for your effort.