# PHP Get the year of most recent occurrance of specific date

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I am working on a script that will determine when a specific calendar date most recently occurred.

This post, [Get the year of a specified month in previous 12 months?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381157/get-the-year-of-a-specified-month-in-previous-12-months), is the basis of my current beta.  It was written for a monthly result and not a specific date.

```
<?php
if (empty($_GET['m'])) {
    $m = "October";
} else {
    $m = htmlspecialchars($_GET['m']);
}

if (empty($_GET['d'])) {
    $d = "1";
} else {
    $d = htmlspecialchars($_GET['d']);
}

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$m = date('m', strtotime($m));

$c = (mktime(0,0,0,$m,$d) < time())
    ? mktime(0,0,0,$m,$d)
    : mktime(0,0,0,$m,$d,date("Y") -1);

$from = date('F jS', $c) . " last occurred in " . date('Y', $c) . ".";

echo $from;
?>
```

The result of the default value, October 1 is:
"October 1st last occurred in 2012."

For June 11th, as a random example:
"June 11th last occurred in 2013."

All date results are TRUE, *except* for the result for February 29th:
"March 1st last occurred in 2013."
Obviously, this is a false statement since the desired result is:
"February 29th last occurred in 2012."

I'm kind of stuck, what is the best way to add a true leap year result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is calculating last true year. Replace with following codes.

```
<?php
if (empty($_GET['m'])) {
    $m = "October";
    } else {
    $m = htmlspecialchars($_GET['m']);
}

if (empty($_GET['d'])) {
    $d = "1";
    } else {
    $d = htmlspecialchars($_GET['d']);
}

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$y = date('Y');
if($m == "February" && $d == "29") $y = $y - ($y % 4);
$m = date('m', strtotime($m));

$c = (mktime(0,0,0,$m,$d) < time()) ? mktime(0,0,0,$m,$d,$y) : mktime(0,0,0,$m,$d,$y);

$from = date('F jS', $c) . " last occurred in " . $y . ".";

echo $from;
?>
```

#### Results

```
For 2013: Result 2012
For 2012: Result 2012
For 2011: Result 2008
For 2010: Result 2008
```

Comment: Thank you. However, this places all previous dates into the last year, including yesterday.  February 29 also becomes March 1. Is there anything else we need to do?

Comment: So set again the year that last true before you getting day. If you set year truely, you'll get right result.

Comment: No sure where things are messing up, but all results are now "December 1st last occurred in 2013."  I do follow your logic of using the true year and not manipulating values for the desired result, however.  Can you check this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$month = 9;
$day = 1;

$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day);
if ($timestamp > time()) {
$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, date('Y') - 1);
}
covert timestamp to your desire format.
```

Comment: This is progress.  Unfortunately, it still forces February 29 to become March 1, and then calculates the last occurrance to be 2013. Thank you.